# Assigning formatted VARCHAR to a local variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume I want a decimal (16501826.00) in SQL Server to be formatted and converted to VARCHAR I am using

`SELECT Format( 16501826 ,'N','en-US')` which will show the result as expected.

[image]

I want this to be assigned to a local variable `@a`

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR;
SET @a = Format( 16501826 ,'N','en-US');
SELECT @a;
```

Returns;

[image]

How do I get the varchar value assigned to @a properly?

Comment: How about `DECLARE @a VARCHAR(13)`?

Comment: When declaring a varchar, you should always define its length, or it defaults to 1. So, `DECLARE @a VARCHAR(100)` should do

Comment: [Bad habits to kick: declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is necessary to assign a length to the VARCHAR result variable, so that the result fits into it:

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(13);
SET @a = Format( 16501826 ,'N','en-US');
SELECT @a;
```

Answer (score 2):

The default length of a `VARCHAR` is a single character. If you need more, you should set the length:

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(n);
```